# PySide: Formatted text in QComboBox

Tags: pyside, qcombobox

I have this snippet of code:

```
import PySide.QtGui

app = PySide.QtGui.QApplication('')
wnd = PySide.QtGui.QWidget()
mly = PySide.QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
combo = PySide.QtGui.QComboBox()

table = [ ('Lorem','ipsum','dolor','sit','amet'),
          ('Aliquam','sodales','nunc','eget','lorem'),
          ('Vivamus','et','sapien','mattis','vulputate'),
          ('Integer','ac','dolor','commodo','cursus'),
          ('Sed','sed','erat','non','magna'),
          ('Duis','vestibulum','eu','tortor','euismod') ]

combo.clear()
for (one,two,three,four,five) in table:
    combo.addItem('%-12s | %-12s | %-12s | %-12s | %-12s' % (one,two,three,four,five))

mly.addWidget(combo)
mly.addStretch(1)
wnd.setLayout(mly)
wnd.show()
app.exec_()
```

I have obtained [this **(1)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJTU5.png) and I'm looking for something like **(2)**: all columns tabulated.

The combobox have the standard proportional font (MS Shell Dlg 2 from QtDesigner). I don't want to use monospaced font.

I have tried to calculate the maximum width in pixels of every column with `combo.fontMetrics().boundingRect(text).width()` and fill every column with spaces:

```
borde = '  '
unspc = ' '
maxwdt = {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0}
for lstlin in table:
    for (ndx,val) in enumerate(lstlin):
        unwdt = combo.fontMetrics().boundingRect(borde + val + borde).width()
        if (unwdt > maxwdt[ndx]):
            maxwdt[ndx] = unwdt

combo.clear()
for lstlin in table:
    txtlin = ''
    for (ndx,val) in enumerate(lstlin):
        txtcmp = borde + val + borde
        while (combo.fontMetrics().boundingRect(txtcmp).width() < maxwdt[ndx]):
            txtcmp += unspc
        txtlin += txtcmp + '|'
    combo.addItem(txtlin)
```

and I have obtained **(3)**.

There are any other method to format a text with proportional font for use in a QComboBox?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine, but it can only be as accurate as the width of a standard space in the proportional font you are using.

To get more accurate results, use the thinnest possible [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) available. For fonts with good unicode support, this will be the `HAIR SPACE U+200A`.

On Linux (using the DejaVu Sans font) I can exactly reproduce **(3)** by changing the following two lines in your example script:

```
# hair-space
unspc = '\u200a'
borde = unspc * 10
```

Comment: Works fine in Linux, Windows 7 and Windows 8. Not work in Windows XP because UTF8 is not enabled, but this solution is enough for me. Thanks!.